# How do I add remember-me login on Silex?

Tags: php, remember-me, silex

I try but don't understand Security core, could anyone help me to add remember-me? I have been waiting several months for @fabpot (https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/pull/464)
Otherwise, I need to rewrite a login for my app, and may be port my app to Symfony :'(
Anyway, I like Silex.

Answer (score 2):

Use the RememberMeServiceProvider: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/remember_me.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to `vendor/silex/silex` folder in your project and run:

```
curl https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/pull/464.patch | git am
```